# How to output random.sample to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, random

I'm trying to output random.sample to a list variable instead of printing it. I want to do this as I want to compare 2 lists.

All i can figure out is how to print it out

**Code:**

```
import random

num1 = int(input("Highest List Number in List 1: "))
num2 = int(input("Highest List Number in List 2: "))

list1 = range(num1)
list2 = range(num2)

print("1st List: ", random.sample(list1,k=10))
print("2nd List: ", random.sample(list2,k=10))
```

Can this be done with random.sample? If not can you advise another random module to try?

Comment: What is the issue? *as is want to compare two lists* - How you want to compare? any logic/condtion?

Comment: just compare the list to pick out similar values

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. With your guidance I was able to get the random output i wanted

```
import random

num1 = int(input("Highest List Number in List 1: "))
num2 = int(input("Highest List Number in List 2: "))

# list(range(5)) + list(range(10,20))
list1 = range(num1)
list2 = range(num2)


first_list = random.sample(list1,k=10)
print(first_list)
second_list = random.sample(list2,k=10)
print(second_list)

for numb in first_list:
    if numb in second_list:
        print(numb)
```

Now i just need to figure out how to print out numb list in a row instead of new line

Comment: `print(numb, end='')` to print in a row.